# Open website in background while visiting image

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to open website in background while visiting image.

i.e. let's say I enter http://websiteloadinginthebackground.freeptp.com/images/free.jpg in browser then image should come as pop up and website should be loaded in background. Just like earlier google images layout.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this using Apache mod rewrite.  You would rewrite the url into something like:

```
 http://websiteloadinginthebackground.freeptp.com?image=free.jpg
```

Your page would load and scripts could read the image parameter out of the URI, loading it into a lightbox or other display on top of the loading page.

You can learn more about changing urls here:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html